# Import mongo_dart package stops text from displaying

Tags: mongodb, dart

The following code works just fine...simply displaying some JSON in an unordered list:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
 // Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_dart-showjson");
  querySelector("#sample_text_id")
      ..onClick.listen(showJSON);
}

void reverseText(MouseEvent event) {
  var text = querySelector("#sample_text_id").text;
  var buffer = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
  querySelector("#sample_text_id").text = buffer.toString();
}

void showJSON(MouseEvent event) {
  var path = 'hcps.json';
  var hcpDisplay = querySelector('#json_length_id');
  HttpRequest.getString(path).then((String fileContents) {
    List<String> hcpList = JSON.decode(fileContents);
    for (int i = 0; i < hcpList.length; i++) {
      hcpDisplay.children.add(new LIElement()..text = hcpList[i].toString());
    }

  });
}
```

However, when I add an import statement for mongo-dart, the JSON is not displayed, though I do not receive an error:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

main() {
  Db db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_dart-showjson");
  querySelector("#sample_text_id")
      ..onClick.listen(showJSON);
}
...
```

The mongo_dart package has been added to pubspec.yaml as a dependency.

Does anyone have an idea as to why importing the mongo_dart package would cause the json text not to display, though there is no error?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use mongo_dart in browser? It is a server side library, it does not work at client side.

Comment: Vadim - the code I pasted in is from a .dart file, not an html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in package readme

> mongo-dart is a server-side driver library for MongoDb implemented in
>   pure Dart

. 
It cannot work at client side. Main reason for that - browsers do not have real sockets to connect to databases like mongodb, mysql, postgress and so on. You may look at some database with a RESTful API like CouchDB. Or you should use some middleware - for example [objectory](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/objectory).

Comment: I missed you `import 'dart:html';` Didn't you get an error message that this library depends on `dart:io` and can't run in the browser?

Comment: Hi, Gunter. Is it question to me or to JesusReagan? AFAIK I did not import `dart:html`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you answered your own question, didn't pay enough attention to see that it was someone else who asked.

Comment: Yes, I do get an error message that 'dart:html' depends on 'dart:io'. I will try implementing objectory. Thank you for the guidance, Vadim and Gunter. Maybe I don't fully understand the division between client and server in Dart, then. By putting the code in question in a .dart file, not an .html file, is that not then server side?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as mdb;

main() {
  mdb.Db db = new mdb.Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_dart-showjson");
```

to see if there is a conflict

You could also add a try/catch block

```dart
try {
  mdb.Db db = new mdb.Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_dart-showjson");
} catch(e) {
  print(e)
}
```

sometimes exceptions are swallowed due to the use of zones (might not help here though) but I think it's worth a try.

It is possible that the package cache directory is corrupted.
You could try

```dart
pub cache repair
```

Comment: Hi Gunter- thanks for the response. Neither of the first two suggestions worked for me. When I try pub cache repair, I get a message saying that there is no subcommand "repair" for "pub cache". When I enter "pub cache -h", I am told that the only available subcommand is 'add'.

Comment: I'm on the development channel. This command was added recently. It seems your version doesn't have it yet.
You could just empty the pub-cache directory. In Linux it's `~/.pub-cache` (don't know on other OS)